# Wine/PoL giving numerous errors in Fedora 17

Tags: fedora, gnome, wine, opengl

I've been trying to run a handful of indy games for Windows on my laptop through Wine, but got a bunch of errors along the lines of:

```
wine: created the configuration directory '/home/jude/.wine'
fixme:storage:create_storagefile Storage share mode not implemented.
err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
fixme:storage:create_storagefile Storage share mode not implemented.
err:winediag:SECUR32_initNTLMSP ntlm_auth was not found or is outdated. Make sure that ntlm_auth >= 3.0.25 is in your path. Usually, you can find it in the winbind package of your distribution.
fixme:iphlpapi:NotifyAddrChange (Handle 0xefe2c8, overlapped 0xefe2e0): stub
p11-kit: couldn't load module: /usr/lib/pkcs11/gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so: /usr/lib/pkcs11/gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
fixme:storage:create_storagefile Storage share mode not implemented.
err:winediag:SECUR32_initNTLMSP ntlm_auth was not found or is outdated. Make sure that ntlm_auth >= 3.0.25 is in your path. Usually, you can find it in the winbind package of your distribution.
fixme:iphlpapi:NotifyAddrChange (Handle 0xece8d0, overlapped 0xece8dc): stub
wine: configuration in '/home/jude/.wine' has been updated.
wine: cannot find L"C:\\windows\\system32\\potatomanseeksdatroof.exe"
```

Play on Linux gives me errors about 32bit OpenGL (I run 64bit)

I've been wrestling with this all day... help?

Comment: You might want to try Wine on itsw own first, and look at the appdb for settings that might be needed...
Most of the messages in your output is fine... The problem there is that it can't find the EXE for the game... (Possibly specifiy a path?)

Comment: You're running a 32-bit Windows program. Therefore you have 32-bit Wine, and it needs 32-bit libraries.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to Chadversary answer, you have to do this to completely silent those warnings:

> err:winediag:SECUR32_initNTLMSP ntlm_auth was not found or is outdated. Make sure that ntlm_auth >= 3.0.25 is in your path. Usually, you can find it in the winbind package of your distribution.

Install the `ntlm_auth` package using `sudo yum install mod_auth_ntlm_winbind` as said [here](http://wiki.winehq.org/NtlmAuthSetupGuide).

> p11-kit: couldn't load module: /usr/lib/pkcs11/gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so: /usr/lib/pkcs11/gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

The `gnome-keyring.i686` package provides this library, but you have to make sure your 32-bit repository is activated, although there [is a bug report](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=823297) that suggest that it might be added to the x86_64 repos later.

> err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot

This suggest that either you are trying to run wine as root or that you installed the 64-bit version of wine for running a 32-bit application. Please check that neither of both are happening.

> fixme:storage:create_storagefile Storage share mode not implemented.
>   fixme:iphlpapi:NotifyAddrChange (Handle 0xefe2c8, overlapped 0xefe2e0): stub
>   fixme:iphlpapi:NotifyAddrChange (Handle 0xece8d0, overlapped 0xece8dc): stub

Those errors happens with almost any application that cannot run natively on wine or that might have problems while trying to run 32-bits apps in 64-bits installations, **try installing the 32-bits libraries for wine first** and hope. A quick search in the WineDB for `potatomanseeksdatroof.exe` didn't yield any results, so you might try theses solutions and if it doesn't work it means that wine don't provide support for that game.

---

### After I had problems with Wine too

Wine stable is too old and wine unstable (beta) could have regressions. You could build and install Wine beta, and see if your problem is solved there. Is a long shot, but it's worth of trying.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have several problems. I can help with this one:

> Play on Linux gives me errors about 32bit OpenGL (I run 64bit)

On a recent Fedora, to install 32bit OpenGL on a 64bit system, do

```
sudo yum install mesa-dri-drivers.i686 mesa-libGL.i686
```

Answer (score 1):

I Found this on the wine website

If a .NET application exits with the following message in console:

```
err:secur32:SECUR32_initSchannelSP TLS library not found, SSL connections will fail
err:winediag:SECUR32_initNTLMSP ntlm_auth was not found or is outdated.
```

Make sure that ntlm_auth >= 3.0.25 is in your path. Usually, you can find it in the winbind package of your distribution.
fixme:rpc:RpcBindingSetAuthInfoExW unsupported AuthnSvc 10
You are missing the samba/winbind component which is essential for certain Wine functionality.

Please install ¨winbind¨ with your distribution package manager!

EDIT:

Tested it on ubuntu with `apt-get install winbind` and it works, I´m not getting the error anymore

Comment: It would be nice if you could provide a link to the actual page where you found this information.  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it more complete.